# Is it possible to get the application pool an applicaiton is running in (without knowing the website beforehand)?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2017, iis-10

I'm running an ASP.NET application (.NET Framework 4.6) on a Windows Server with IIS 10.

I've read a few examples where you get the application pool for specific sites.

```
ServerManager manager = new ServerManager();
Site defaultSite = manager.Sites["Default Web Site"];

foreach (Application app in defaultSite.Applications)
{
    Console.WriteLine(
        "{0} is assigned to the '{1}' application pool.", 
        app.Path, app.ApplicationPoolName);
}
```

But in these examples I have to define the Website (as far as I understand) under which the application is running.

Now when I don't want to fixate that in the source code (as it can change), I'm wondering how can I get under which application pool name is the application running?

Comment: An application must be queries from a site, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis That's how IIS was designed.

Comment: @LexLi still though when I configure the site I can give it a Name. But in the above example I would Need to know the Name already at coding time AND could never Change it........and in IIS I can easily Change the Name of the site, which is what could happen easily)

Comment: Rarely people change site name. But if you want to use something constant, that's the site ID.

Comment: @Thomas if not wanting to hard code the value, why not store it in `*.config` file appSettings and extract it via `ConfigurationManager` as needed/

Comment: @Nkosi also an option though can't it be read out somewhere? (normally a program SHOULD know who it is itself?)

Comment: `var siteName = HostingEnvironment.SiteName; Site currentSite = manager.Sites[siteName];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the current site name and path via the [`HostingEnvironment.SiteName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.sitename?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [`HostingEnvironment.ApplicationVirtualPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.applicationvirtualpath?view=netframework-4.7.2) respectively.

With them, getting the desired information from the server manager can be done like

```
using Microsoft.Web.Administration;
using System.Web.Hosting;

//...

var manager = new ServerManager();

var siteName = HostingEnvironment.SiteName;

var site = manager.Sites[siteName];

var applicationPath = HostingEnvironment.ApplicationVirtualPath;

var application = site.Applications[applicationPath];

Console.WriteLine(
    "{0} is assigned to the '{1}' application pool.", 
    application.Path, application.ApplicationPoolName);

var appPoolName = application.ApplicationPoolName;

var applicationPool = manager.ApplicationPools[appPoolName];
```